# Is there a Java implementation of an indexer in mapreduce?

Tags: java, mapreduce, information-retrieval

I have a list of URLs and I want to download them in order to create an index in webtrec format. I've found an useful framework called **MapReduce** (Apache Hadoop) but I'd like to know if there is an implementation in java of what I want to do. Or may be a close example of it.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Java Map/Reduce framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260212/simple-java-map-reduce-framework)

Comment: You might want to look into Nutch - http://nutch.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce pattern is a pattern for parallelizable, CPU-bound computations in multiple steps. Downloading and crawling web pages is an I/O-bound operation. Hence, you should differentiate both operations.

So you should first use something like a queue and asynchronous I/O for downloading web sites when performance is really that important. In a second step, you can then use MapReduce for building the actual index.

Hadoop is one possibility, but if you're not targeting large scale, frameworks such as Fork/Join and akka may be applicable as well.