# Parallel.For in Java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Parallel.For” for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010185/parallel-for-for-java)

.NET has Parallel.For which lets you run a for loop in parallel without having to play around with threads directly.

[Details are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx)

Is there something similar in Java? I found the exact same question ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010185/parallel-for-for-java)), however it was asked before the latest version of java came out, which claims to have:

"Concurrency utilities under JSR 166"

So, did they put something in?

Comment: I believe your question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4010275/1221734).

Comment: I foudn that question. I linked to it. I'm wondering if there's something OFFICIAL.

Comment: @MarkByers - I already said that myself. I linked to the exact same question up there. I'm asking if they put something in there in Java 1.7 - which occured between that post and now.

Comment: There is nothing officially from Oracle which says equivalent for X in .NET is Y in Java.

Comment: Parallel processing can be done with the Fork/Join framework as indicated in one of the answers in the thread you point to. But Parallel.For seems to also use delegates (I think that's what it is called in C#), which should be introduced in Java 8 - except that they are called lambda expressions.

Answer (score 3):

While it could be suggested that Parallel.For is simular to ExecutorService.submit, I suspect it is not.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    int runs1 = 1000;
    final int[] a = new int[100];
    for (int j = 0; j < runs1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i] * a[i];
        }
    }
    long time1 = System.nanoTime() - start1;
    System.out.printf("Each loop took an average of %,d micro-seconds%n", time1 / runs1 / 1000);

    int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);
    for (int j = 0; j < runs1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            final int i2 = i;
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    a[i2] = a[i2] * a[i2];
                }
            });
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
    System.out.printf("Parallel: Each loop took an average of %,d micro-seconds%n", time2 / runs1 / 1000);
}
```

prints

```
Each loop took an average of 2 micro-seconds
Parallel: Each loop took an average of 149 micro-seconds
```

This shows that in this example, using multiple threads is a **very bad idea**.  So I would hope that the loop is the slightly more efficient

```
    for (int j = 0; j < runs1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < processors; i++) {
            final int i2 = i;
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i3 = i2 * 100 / processors; i3 < (i2 + 1) * 100 / processors && i3 < 100; i3++)
                        a[i2] = a[i2] * a[i2];
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

prints

```
Parallel: Each loop took an average of 28 micro-seconds
```

If you consider that the code in the Runnable is not thread safe, I suspect Parallel.For does something rather different or its pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Fork/Join Framework should be included with Java 8, along with lambdas/closures... Just recently there was a good speech on that subject by Angelika Langer, one of Java Champions

Answer (score 1):

My Parallel Computing professor, Alan Kaminsky, and his herd of graduate students have written a library that has the features you need.

Javadocs, licences, downloads, and even a free book are all covered on the information page.

It's Free Software under the GNU GPL version 3.

[Parallel Java 2 Library](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/pj2.shtml)