# How speed up for loop without increasing memory (easy and simple way)?

Tags: java

I have simple loop:

```
   List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
               results.add("a" + i + "b");
            }

    return results;
```

must be simple idea- because if I will start to create thread pool, I will spend memory for additional objects, also without java8.

How can I implement simple parallel loop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Parallel.For" for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010185/parallel-for-for-java)

Comment: What is the type of `results`?  I _strongly_ doubt parallelism will work for you in this case, or that there's any better way to do it.

Comment: `"a"` and `"b"` are always the same?

Comment: @Jean Jung yes, and  results - is list of strings

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need 100000000 identical strings?

Comment: @ Joekomino - task on optimization where I stuck

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `"a" + "b"` and not `"ab"` ?

Comment: @Joekomino and problem is - it must work 10 times faster

Comment: could you use 1 "ab" string and refer to it as and when you need it?

Comment: @wero can you add more info ?

Comment: @MaxUsanin It would help if you added more info. What are you doing with the results? What's your actual loop creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done parralel for a simple reason: Java doesn't provide an efficient `List` implementation for concurrent access.

The simplest solution would be to implement an own `LinkedList` and link several `LinkedLists` into one, which can be done a lot faster and in parralel. The merge-operation can afterwards be done in `O(1)`.

Comment: and perform these operations in parallel ? after to merge the LinkedList(s)?

Comment: @MaxUsanin no fill several LinkedLists in parrallel and merge them afterwards. You'll have to implement the list on your own.

Comment: @Kayaman the only list is `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and  as for the efficiency: the underlying array is copied on each write, nothing more to be said.

Comment: You're right (after the edit) about no `List` implementation besides `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. However considering how vague the question is, he might be able to  use for example [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html).

Comment: I will thumb up for your suggestion, because it sounds like map reduce approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to speed this up is to create an ArrayList with the size that you need ahead of time. I have no idea why you would need a list like this, but I can only assume that your program is slowing down everytime it has to allocate and copy another array because it ran out of space.

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(10000000);
```

Comment: I upvoted but looking back, this does not populate the array

Comment: No it allocates it ahead of time with initial capacity.

Comment: yes it is fresh idea but it can not speed up to ten times

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 parallell streams you can do this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 100000000)
         .parallel()
         .mapToObj(i -> new StringBuilder()
                               .append("a")
                               .append(i)
                               .append("b")
                               .toString())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First, `IntStream.range(0, 100000000)` creates an `IntStream` with the values 0 to 100000000 (exclusive). Then, the `IntStream` is made parallel using the `parallel` method. Then, I use `mapToObj` in order to make the `IntStream` into a `Stream<String>`. At last, the stream will be collected in a `List`. I also use a `StringBuilder` to make the string concatenation a bit faster.

Comment: He said "without java8"

Comment: Still useful for others who might stumble upon this question.